# Why is `typedef struct x x` allowed?

Tags: c

I was reading the book [modern C](http://freecomputerbooks.com/Modern-C-by-Jens-Gustedt.html) and was suprised to find that the following code works

```c
typedef struct point point;
struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main() {
   point p = { .x = 1, .y = 2 };
}
```

However, the book does not go in detail about that. How does that work? Why does `point` in `main()` refer to the `typedef` since `struct point` is defined *after* that?

Comment: Structure tags and `typedef` names exist in two different name spaces, so they never conflict.  It's always clear from context which one you mean, since the structure tag always follows the keyword `struct`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works because C has multiple *name spaces*:

- labels (disambiguated by `goto` or trailing `:`);
- tag names for `struct`, `enum`, and `union` (disambiguated by the `struct`, `union`, or `enum` keywords):
- names for `struct` and `union` members (disambiguated by a leading `.` or `->`, each `struct` or `union` type acts as its own namespace, so different `struct` and `union` types can use the same member names);
- all other identifiers (variable and function names, typedef names, enumeration constants, etc.).

So you can use the same name as a label, a tag name, a member name, and a regular identifier all in the same code, and the compiler is able to distinguish between them:

```
struct x { int x; }; // tag name, member name

void foo( struct x x ) // tag name, all other identifiers
{
  if ( x.x ) // all other identifiers, member name
    goto x;  // label name

  // do something here

  x: printf( "At label x\n" ); // label name
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The line `typedef struct point point;` does two things:

- It creates a **forward declaration** of `struct point`
- It creates a type alias for `struct point` called `point`.

Forward declarations are useful if you need to know a struct exits before it is fully defined, for example:

```
typedef struct x X;

typedef struct y {
    int a;
    X *x;
} Y;

 struct x {
     int b;
     Y *y;
 };
```

Comment: I think that `typedef struct x X;` should be `typedef struct X X;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `struct foo` in many places before `struct foo { ... }` is defined. This is known as an "incomplete type".

It's useful because it lets you define abstract types:

*foo_header.h*

```
struct foo;  // abstract
struct foo *foo_create(void);
void do_stuff_with(struct foo *);
void foo_destroy(struct foo *);
```

This way users of the library can use struct pointers and functions that work on these pointers without knowing how the struct is actually defined, which is nice for encapsulation.

It's also used in recursive types:

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;  // struct node isn't defined yet!
};
// here the definition of struct node is complete
```

C supports it because it's easy to implement: To compile code that uses `struct foo *`, the compiler only has to know how big the pointer is. It doesn't care about the struct members.

Similarly, in your `typedef` example, the compiler doesn't need to know the details of the struct to create a type alias for it.

Answer (score 1):

This example comes straight from C standard, Section 6.7.2.3:

> The following alternative formulation uses the typedef mechanism:

```
typedef struct tnode TNODE;
struct tnode {
 int count;
 TNODE *left, *right;
};
TNODE s, *sp;
```

What it does it forward declares struct, and than creates a type alias for it.